# Split Inputvalue into 2 hex encoded bytes if Input>255

Tags: c#, beginner

I'm assigning a HEX-Value to a byte in a byte array and then send this byte array to a serial port. If the value is bigger than 255 the corresponding HEX-Value is supposed to be split into two.

Example: `750 = 0x2EE` so `A[0] = 0x2` and `A[1] = 0xEE`

Is this an efficient way to do the task that I want it to do? From what I read so far the conversion should be okay here or can I skip the `0x` and still get the same result after the `Convert.ToByte`?

```
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        byte[] A = new byte[2];
        string f = "0x" + Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text).ToString("X");
        textBox2.Text = Convert.ToString(f.Length);  //to test length
        if (f.Length < 5)
        {
            A[0] = 0x00;
            A[1] = Convert.ToByte(f,16);
            textBox1.Text = "A";
        }
        else if (f.Length == 5)
        {
            A[0] = Convert.ToByte(f.Substring(0,3),16);
            A[1] = Convert.ToByte("0x" + f.Substring(3),16);
            textBox1.Text = "B" + "Sub0: " + f.Substring(0, 3) + "\r\n Sub1 :" + "0x" + f.Substring(3); //to test
        }
        else
        {
            textBox1.Text = "Falsche Eingabe";
        }      
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Why try and manipulate the number as a string?

Personally I would convert the input to a number and then manipulate it and finally convert it back to a string, if you need to.  However I would have thought C# has a way of making a text box accept Hex numbers and returning an Int (I don't know I don't do GUIs.)

Using your example number `0x2ee`.
If the number if greater than `0xFF` then it will take more than one byte to store it.  So to split the value you can do `lowerByte = number % 256`.  The upper byte is simply `upperByte = (number - lowerByte) >> 8`

So putting this into code

```
static byte[] SplitNumber (Int16 number)
{
    byte[] returnValue = new byte[2];
    returnValue[0] = Convert.ToByte(number % 256);
    returnValue[1] = Convert.ToByte((number - returnValue[0]) >> 8);
    return returnValue;
}
```

Now you have your bytes, you can format them in the text box as you like,

Comment: Did you mean to use the `&` and not the `%` modulo operator? With `%` you'll get `0xF0` = 240 which is invalid.